# how to know if my GPU is used by my code from task manager?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

The figure below is my task manager while execution of tensorflow python program.

how to know if my GPU is used by my code?
why the GPU usage does't go up to 90% ??

[image]

The performance of Cuda usage is 0%.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `Cuda` or `Compute` tab depending on your GPU model (see the bottom right graph on the screenshot).
[image]

Comment: I selected Cuda and it's showing 0% .

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer of my question and i hope it may help another one.

The 8% in GPU usage appears to correlate with the "3D" graph. And as my program does't use the 3D i was misleaded and i thought i'm not using the GPU.